# What's wrong with this Ruby code to determine whether a number is prime?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm getting `"true"`

```
def is_prime(n)
  if (2..(n**0.5)).each {|i| n % i != 0}
    puts "true"
  else
    puts "false"
  end
end

is_prime(14)
```

Comment: You need `all?` rather than `each`.

Comment: If you call `each` on any collection, when the method will be finished its execuion, you would get the same collection back. In ruby all objects are `true` except `nil` and `false`. Thus your `if` always evaluated as `true`. so you are getting `"true"`.

Comment: Thanks Cary and Arup!

Answer (score 5):

Cary Swoveland hit the main problem, but there are some other tweaks that might make it cleaner/more useful.

```
def is_prime?(n)
  (2..(n**0.5)).all? {|i| n % i != 0}
end

p is_prime? 14      # false
p is_prime? 17      # true
```

Note the addition of the question mark in the method name.  The method now returns a usable result instead of printing.

If you wanted to enhance performance you could test separately for evenness and then iterate over only the odd numbers 3 to sqrt(n), stepping by 2's to cut the amount of work in half:

```
def is_prime?(n)
  if n.odd?
    3.step(Math.sqrt(n).to_i, 2).all? {|i| n % i != 0}
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to use floating point numbers for divisibility tests? It calls for error with larger numbers, and at the very least it's not as fast as it would be with integers. Something like `(2..((n**0.5 + 10).to_i)).all?` would probably be the safer bet.

Comment: @NiklasB. `.to_i` is almost certainly a good idea for the square root.